# How to enter interactive boot mode on ubuntu linux system

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

On Ubuntu 10.04, How to enter interactive mode at boot time?
Can I choose which driver to be enabled? or which Service to be enabled?

System blocked at boot time, and closed screen display -- no signal to the monitor.

How to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can I up the question by add comments?

Comment: Adding a comment can "bump" a question back onto the front page, if that's what you mean. I suggest asking over on askbuntu.com, the Stack Exchange site specific to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "recovery mode" from the grub menu (hold down the left shift key during boot up to get to the grub menu).

Comment: I entered recovery mode, but it closed my screen, I can't see any words, I can't shoot the trouble. When I heard a "po" when the system starting, then the screen was closed (suspended mode, not only blacked).
Can I get which driver or service got my screen closed from syslog?

Comment: can you recommend a article to introduce the trouble shooting of linux boot up?

Answer (score 0):

If the screen goes blank before you can actually enter the Grub menu, it might be motherboard/BIOS issue. Have you tried with another monitor?